# Multimodule Maven project in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, pom.xml, parent-pom

**Issue**: For some reason my main application can't import classes from other modules.

Also I don't see the compiled output of Data and Remote modules getting included in main Main:war: exploded under WEB-INF/classes under Module Settings (IntelliJ)

**Main application**

```
<groupId>com.example.entitlement</groupId>
<artifactId>service</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>Data</module>
    <module>Remote</module>
</modules>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

**Data Module**

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.example.entitlement</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>data</artifactId>
```

**Remote Module**

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.example.entitlement</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>remote</artifactId>
```

---

### Edit

I've added dependencies as suggested.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example.entitlement</groupId>
        <artifactId>data</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example.entitlement</groupId>
        <artifactId>remote</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

### Edit

My directory structure

[image]

Comment: Can you build by Maven from command line?

Comment: To add a dependency in a Maven project on another maven module you should include it into `dependencies` section. See examples at http://www.codetab.org/tutorial/apache-maven/multi-module/multi-module-project and https://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-how-to-create-a-multi-module-project/

Comment: @Andrey I've added dependencies, see my edit please. problem is persisting though though, my web module can't import submodules. attached a screenshot as well.

Comment: @Andrey I'm still having issues. Parent module is unable to see child. I've followed the links and I can confirm that my parent pom refers to two sub modules under `</modules></modules>` along with listing both under `<dependencies>`. Both child pom refers to parent via `<parent>` tag. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The exception is that my parent module is a project itself, it's not empty, it has source files that's importing those two submodules. The parent project has to be empty??

Comment: You can also give the below a try.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6jirc1x25U