# Could not find artifact junit:unit:jar:5.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Error

> Could not find artifact junit:junit:jar:5.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

Screenshot from IntelliJ

[image]

attempts:

1. mvn clean and install didn't work
2. File -> clean caches and restart didn't work
3. deleting .m2 directory didn't work.

Comment: How do you know use junit 5.0. highest version of junit is 4.13.x

Comment: check maven repo https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit

Comment: To run JUnit 5 tests through maven you need to add dependencies  junit-jupiter-api and junit-jupiter-engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use JUnit5, please use below dependency -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And, if you want to use JUnit4, please use below dependency -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @Developer please post new question with details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55569601/multimodule-maven-project-in-intellij